# Grouping by increasing stateDuration resets using Flux in InfluxDb

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I am recording period between application heartbeats into Influxdb.
The "target" period is 2000ms.
If the period is above 2750ms, then it is defined as a "lag event".

My end objective is to run statistics on "how long" we are running without lag events.

I switched to Flux from Influxql, so that i could use the stateDuration() method.
Using the below method, i am able to collect the increasing durations. At lag events, the state_duration is then reset to -1.

```
from (bucket: "sampledb/autogen")
|> range(start: -1h)
|> filter(fn: (r) =>
  r._measurement == "timers" and
  r._field == "HeartbeatMs" and
  r.character == "Tarek"
  )
|> stateDuration(fn: (r) => 
    r._value<=2750,
    column: "state_duration",
    unit: 1s
   )
|> keep(columns: ["_time","state_duration"])
```

At this point, I would like to be able to collect 'max(state_duration)' for each duration between lag events, and this is where i get stuck. Trying to "group by every new stateDuration sequence"/"group by increasing stateDurations"...

I was thinking that it might be possible to use "reduce()" or "map()" to inject a sequence number that i can use to group by, somehow increasing that sequence number whenever i have a -1 in the state_duration.

Below is a graph of the "state_duration" when running the flux query, i am basically trying to capture the value at the top of each peak.

[image]

Any help is appreciated, including doing this e.g. in InfluxQL or with Continuous Queries.

Data looks like below when exported to csv:

```
"time","timers.HeartbeatMs","timers.character"
"2021-01-12T14:49:34.000+01:00","2717","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:36.000+01:00","1282","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:38.000+01:00","2015","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:40.000+01:00","1984","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:42.000+01:00","2140","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:44.000+01:00","1937","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:46.000+01:00","2405","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:48.000+01:00","2312","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:50.000+01:00","1453","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:52.000+01:00","1890","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:54.000+01:00","2077","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:56.000+01:00","2250","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:49:59.000+01:00","2360","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:00.000+01:00","1453","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:02.000+01:00","1952","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:04.000+01:00","2108","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:06.000+01:00","2485","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:08.000+01:00","1437","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:10.000+01:00","2421","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:12.000+01:00","1483","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:14.000+01:00","2344","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:17.000+01:00","2437","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:18.000+01:00","1092","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:20.000+01:00","1969","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:22.000+01:00","2359","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:24.000+01:00","2140","Tarek"
"2021-01-12T14:50:27.000+01:00","2421","Tarek"
```

Comment: Have you got solution for this? I am trying to do same and am stuck as well.

Comment: Im sorry no. Havent pursued it much either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of. One is to look for the inverted state. The other is to use elapsed() to find interval + timeShift() to emulate LAG().

I don't like the latter though I think the first is not intuitive neither :-(. Really hope features like LAG() or CurrentRecordIndex() would be available in Flux.

```
from (bucket: "sampledb/autogen")
|> range(start: -1h)
|> filter(fn: (r) =>
  r._measurement == "timers" and
  r._field == "HeartbeatMs" and
  r.character == "Tarek"
  )
|> stateDuration(fn: (r) => 

    r._value>2750,         // Look for the inverted state

    column: "inverted_state_duration",
    unit: 1s
  )
|> keep(columns: ["_time","inverted_state_duration"])

// Clear out records of the periods you are after
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["inverted_state_duration"] == -1)

// Calculate the gap duration with elapsed()
|> elapsed(columnName: "state_duration")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["state_duration"] > ${ max(stateDuration.unit, record interval) })
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't looked at this for a long time, but i was able to solve it using the timeShift() method to emulate LAG()

Btw, i was almost, but not quite enable to run the example code provided, it fails on the last greater than statement.
As i used timeShift instead, i didnt pursue that bug any more